# C# Add rows/columns to existing DataTable in separate method

Tags: c#, methods, datatable, addition

EDIT: Sorry guys, I was a little blind with this thing, I posted the "solution" below under the "problem".

ORIGINAL:

I can't seem to get behind this problem (even after searching a lot on SO):
I have a DataTable object that I want to "prepare" for data population like so:

My model class property (classname "DataMdl"):

```
    private static DataTable _datatbl;
    public DataTable datatbl
    {
        get { return _datatbl; }
        set
        {
            _datatbl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("datatbl"));
        }
    }
```

Call of prepdatatable in a ViewModel-Method:

```
 prepdatatable(DataMdl.datatbl, 5, 9)
```

My prepdatatable method:

```
 private void prepdatatable(DataTable dt, int rowcount, int colcount)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < colcount; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("col" + i);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("row" + i);
        }
    }
```

After calling the above method I try to populate the DataTable in the method which called prepdatatable with

```
  DataMdl.datatbl.Rows[0][0] = "..."
  DataMdl.datatbl.Rows[0][1] = "..."
  ...
  DataMdl.datatbl.Rows[1][0] = "..."
  ...
  and so on
```

In this case I get a NullReferenceException on DataMdl.datatbl.

When I try to initialize DataMdl.datatbl outside of prepdatatable, I get a NullReferenceException inside on "dt" inside prepdatatable.

"SOLUTION":
Just make prepdatatable return a DataTable instead of void and then assign its value to the property DataMdl.datatbl:

```
  private DataTable prepdatatable(int rowcount, int colcount)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < colcount; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("col" + i);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("row" + i);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

and

```
   DataMdl.datatbl = prepdatatable(5, 9);
```

Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Where do you get this exception? Is `datatbl = new DataTable();` the only location where you initialize the table before you pass it to the method?

Comment: You are adding rows and columns correctly. I think you are passing `null` instead of datatable to this method

Comment: _"EDIT: "datatbl" is a property of my model class."_ Then show the relevant  real code instead of code that works. We cannot fix an issue that doesn't exist.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `DataMdl.datatbl`?

Comment: You could make it `ref` or you need to reassign the `DataTable` to the property afterwards. Apart from that, accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here?

```
    for (i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
    {
        var r = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```

I have a feeling that this is the source of the exception. Take a look at this: [How to add a new row to c# DataTable in 1 line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748433/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-c-sharp-datatable-in-1-line-of-code) . It seems like you are trying to add a row that doesn't have a value. A new row is, by default, null, but initialized. Then, you try to add it to the datatable. Why don't you add rows like you are adding columns?

Answer (score 0):

suppose that this is the initialization of your datatable and here you are calling the method

```
datatbl = new DataTable();
 prepdatatable(datatbl, 5, 9);
```

this method will not take the datatable , it will take a copy from it , you are sending the datatable by value not by reference

```
private void prepdatatable(DataTable dt, int rowcount, int colcount)
    {
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < colcount; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("col" + i);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
    }
```

I will suppose that your method should work fine and the problem is only in the parameter sending way
just change 
the method call to

```
prepdatatable(ref datatbl, 5, 9);
```

the header to

```
  private void prepdatatable(ref DataTable dt, int rowcount, int colcount)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah, I thought it should be something like this, unfortunately I get an error saying that a property can not be passed as a reference.

Comment: You got me on the right track though, I posted my "solution" above.